# Can I auto archive my Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

We are using Google Spreadsheets for call logs, which is shared with more than 20 users and we all add entries simultaneously.

I would like to know if there is any feature to automatically archive old entries on the spreadsheet?

Comment: If you want a time stamp to every entry you do you can use Google Forms which produces Google Spreadsheet. You can then do conditional sorting in that spreadsheet to narrow down the results.

Comment: ... or see [Date and time stamp automatically added in column](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57454/date-and-time-stamp-automatically-added-in-column/57461#57461)

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheets has its own revision control system, and it's accessible from File > See revision history. That is probably the closest you can get for an automatic archival system.